# cypher - sum on all subnodes in graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like [image]
What I need is to get sum of property X for every node that is connected to HPKP-X node.

The query that gives me everything on the path is this the results are in this image:
[image]

```
MATCH (p:Project{key:"HPKP"})-[*]-(i:Issue) 
RETURN i.key, i.worklog
```

But I want it grouped by HPKP-X nodes and exclude the relates relationship (see the picture 1).

So far i got to this

```
MATCH c = (p:Project{key:"HPKP"})-[r:CONTAINS]->(i:Issue)-[x*]-(s:Issue) 
WHERE NONE(x in relationships(c) where type(x) = "RELATES") 
RETURN distinct i.key, sum(i.worklog)
```

But that is duplicating my sum results. So what do I need is query that will give me result with this:

```
HPKP-3 worklog = HPKP-3.worklog + MIKA-3.worklog = 100 + 100 = 200
HPKP-2 worklog = HPKP-2.worklog + MIKA-2.worklog = 200 + 200 = 400
HPKP-1 worklog ......
```

Comment: what are the values of your three `Project` nodes?

Comment: I just need the graph for project with the key:"HPKP". The other project nodes are here just for clarification because one node can be part of graph on more projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know all the relationship types that you want to whitelist (e.g., `CAUSES` and `SPLITS`), you can use the APOC function [apoc.path.subgraphNodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_to_nodes_in_a_subgraph) to get the subgraph nodes (consisting of only `Issue` nodes) reachable from each `Issue` node `CONTAINED` by the `Project` of interest:

```
MATCH c = (p:Project{key:"HPKP"})-[:CONTAINS]->(i:Issue)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(i, {
  relationshipFilter: 'CAUSES|SPLIT',
  labelFilter: '+Issue',
  maxLevel: 10,
  filterStartNode: false}) YIELD node
RETURN i.key AS key, SUM(node.worklog) AS total_worklog;
```

Note: The above example uses 10 as the required `maxLevel`, to limit how deeply to search for nodes. A maxLevel that is too high can cause the query to run out of memory or to take too long (if there are indeed long paths in the DB).